# Close Mat-menu when user scrolls the window

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-material2, viewchild

Problem: Should't visible mat-menu When Window Scrolls on top of nav menu,

Cause: it rises because of high `z-index` in `.cdk-overlay-container`

I have trailed following

**file.ts**

```
@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: MatMenuTrigger; 
@HostListener('window:scroll', [])
scrollHandler() {
if (this.trigger) {
this.trigger.closeMenu();
 }
 }
```

But which is worked only for first mat-menu out of 6, rest not closing on scroll !!!!!

[Angular Cli Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYMFT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @ViewChildren(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: QueryList<MatMenuTrigger>;
 @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
 scrollHandler() {
     for (let index = 0; index < this.trigger.toArray().length; index++) {
   this.trigger.toArray()[index].closeMenu();
 }
```

this will access all the mat-menus inside the component and the loop will iterate over each index and closes the menu opened.